# Is there some way to tell SAS that for any obs ####1, ####2, or ####3 (where # = 1-9), I want them formatted #### Spring, #### Fall, and #### Winter?

Tags: formatting, sas

So I have a 1000 observations for one variable that look like this:

```
19962
19943
19972
19951
19951
19912
```

The first four digits vary a bit, but the last digit is always 1, 2, or 3.  Is there a way to only format the last digit, while not having to type out each iteration of the first four digits in a `value` statement?

That is, I want to avoid doing this:

```
proc format;
value varfmt 
  19911 = '1991 Spring'
  19912 = '1991 Fall'
  19913 = '1991 Winter'
  19921 = '
  19922 = '
  […]
  19991 = '1999 Spring'
  19992 = '1999 Fall'
  19993 = '
  ;
run;
```

Instead, is there some way to tell SAS that for any `####1`, `####2`, or `####3`, I want `#### Spring`, `#### Fall`, and `#### Winter` (which would be three lines under the `value` statement)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This would also be a great place to use PROC FCMP and define a custom function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are applying the format on the last digit only, so using the all the digits in the proc format is not required. Just extract the last digit and apply the format on it and concatenate it with other first four digits.

Creating the sample dataset

```
data test;
infile datalines;
input year;
datalines;
19962
19943
19972
19951
19951
19912
;
run;
```

Creating the formats

```
proc format;
value $varfmt
1 = 'Spring'
2 = 'Fall'
3 = 'Winter'
;
run;
```

Here, doing the following things

1. Extracting the last digit
2. Applying the format on it, created above
3. Extracting the first four digits of the number
4. Concatenating the output of 2 and 3

---

```
data final;
set test;
year_new = cat(substr(compress(year),1,4)," ",put(substr(compress(year),5,1),$varfmt.));
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

You also have the option of creating a format from a dataset, if you do want a format for the whole value.  You will have to create all possible rows, but it's not particularly hard.

```
data forfmt;
  fmtname='SEASONF';
  length start $5 label $8;
  do startyr = 1990 to 2015;
    start=cats(startyr,'1');
    label=catx(' ',startyr,'Spring');
    output;
    start=cats(startyr,'2');
    label=catx(' ',startyr,'Fall');
    output;
    start=cats(startyr,'3');
    label=catx(' ',startyr,'Winter');
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format cntlin=forfmt;
quit;
```